# Problem : The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No Symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, debug-symbols

I have been working on Visual Studio 2005 since last couple of days. Till yestarday it was working fine. Suddenly it stopped working for debugging. For every breakpoints I used to work with it is giving me 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No Symbols have been loaded for this document' error.

I tried all the possible solutions found over net as;
1. Clean and rebuild solution.
2. Deleted pdb files and rebuild the solution. 
3. Deleted all the files from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files and rebuild the solution. 
4. Changed the debug location as well.

Still nothing is happening. I am really frustrated with this issue, since no solution is working.

Please help me to get out of this.

Thanks in advance
Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the symbols not loaded error appears when your pdb file is placed in the wrong location. Goto your project properties and check if the output is going to the same location as you had set earlier. If yes, reset your project output location and rebuild the solution. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I checked that it is pointing to the location where it was previously. I deleted all the pdb files and recompiled the solution. Still it is having the same issue.

Comment: I had asked you to edit the project output directory in the project properties, and not delete and rebuild. Deleting the pdb is the same as cleaning, and this will not be effective. Change location before rebuilding.

Comment: Yes I tried that as well but my bad luck it is still not loading symbols.

Comment: why is this set as the answer?